# Do I really stink or are people just being mean?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

I noticed this thing. People do seem to talk about nasty smell when I bump into them or get close. Some are pretty direct:

> *"You smell like sh!t sir!"*

I overheard similar insult with spanish accent with *puto* at the end. Some are indirect, such as woman exclaiming:

> *"What's that awful stench?!"*

I wonder if this is actually directed at CJ. If it is, is it indication of some stat, such as low sex appeal? Can I fix it? Or is it just random talk?

Comment: That moment when you see this on HNQ sidebar...

Comment: @traisjames in this site, the game is referred to in the tags. In this case [Grand Theft Auto: San Andreas](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gta-san-andreas).

Comment: That moment where the tag is **mandatory** context...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

According to a [Gamefaqs thread on the matter](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/914983-grand-theft-auto-san-andreas/40854687), there are 3 ways to fix this:

1. Go swim in the ocean;
2. Go save your game;
3. Equip a fresh set of clothes.

Comment: No showers in this game?

Comment: @ShadowWizard nope, no showers AFAIK. Haven't played the game in over a year though since Windows 10 doesn't like it, so I might have forgotten certain things.

Comment: More likely they just focus on other things. Anyway thanks for the good answer! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Considering the fact that SA includes dating and even a hidden [mini game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Coffee_mod) where you actually sleep with women, the ability to shower would have definitely not been out of place.

Comment: @Fiksdal so probably shower is not exciting enough, same way most games don't include toilets.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Haha.. That would have been great, though. There could be like a "dump-meter" on the screen that keeps increasing, eventually forcing you to go. You don't want that to happen in the middle of a mission :)

Comment: Like Maxis's The Sims - there is a bladder pressure meter and if you don't use the toilet you*will* wet yourself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - Come again?  I've seen toilets in plenty of games, primiarily within the FPS genre, and also in a fair number of RPG's.  Usually the game will even let you 'interact' with a (non-broken) toilet.

Comment: @aroth - Sure, but in how many of said games them do you actually need to interact with them in the 'usual' way? In Fallout 3, you *can* drink from them but isn't required. In Fallout 4, you can sit on them, but it's not like your character uses them as anything more than just a regular seat. Just because a game's bathroom features  a toilet model doesn't mean the game forces you to 'use' it. :-)